# Will if-else statements nest without brackets?

Tags: c++, c, if-statement

I want to write something utterly ridiculous that calls for a great depth of conditional nesting.  The least disorienting way to write this is to forgo brackets entirely, but I have not been able to find any info on if nesting single-statement if-else guards is legal; the non-nested version causes people enough problems it seems.

Is it valid to write the following? (In both C and C++, please let me know if they differ on this.)

```cpp
    float x = max(abs(min), abs(max));
    uint32 count = 0u;

    // divides and conquers but, tries to shortcut toward more common values

    if (x < 100'000.f) 
        if (x < 10.f) 
            count = 1u;
        else
            if(x < 1'000.f)
                if (x < 100.f) 
                    count = 2u;
                else
                    count = 3u;
            else 
                if (x < 10'000.f) 
                    count = 4u;
                else
                    count = 5u;
    else 
        ... // covers the IEEE-754 float32 range to ~1.0e+37 (maybe 37 end branches)
```

*--skippable lore--*

The underlying puzzle (this is for fun) is that I want to figure out the number of glyphs necessary to display a float's internal representation without rounding/truncation, in constant time. Counting the fractional part's glyph count in constant time was much neater/faster, but unfortunately I wasn't able to figure out any bit-twiddling tricks for the integer part, so I've decided to just brute-force it.  Never use math when you can use your fists.

Comment: nesting `if-else` like that is legal.

Comment: The `u` integer suffixes are redundant.

Comment: Nesting `if`-`else` without using `{}` is legal.     `{}` are needed if multiple statements are needed for any condition.   For example `if (x == 1) x = 2; else y = 3;` is fine, but `if (x == 1) x = 2; a = 2; else y = 3;` is not (and the `{}` would be needed to turn that into `if (x == 1) {x = 2; a = 2;} else y = 3;`)

Comment: The relevant grammar of an [if statement](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if) is `if (condition) statement_true else statement_false`. The entire thing is a single statement, and therefore can be used as a `statement_true` or `statement_false` without needing to be wrapped in curly braces to form a compound statement.

Comment: The third ```else``` is not exactly lined up with the ```if``` above it (off by one space). I'm neither discouraging nor encouraging this approach, but misalignment is an example of why some frown on the practice, legal or not.

Comment: @sj95126 - ah, I'll fix it, I must've introduced it when reformatting for SO

Comment: Um, have you just reinvented `log10()`?  The ghost of John Napier called and wants to challenge you to a boxing match...

Comment: Or if you insist on a chain of comparisons, you could populate an array with `{1.0f, 10.0f, 100.0f, ...}` and binary-search to find where your value would fall in it.  Gets down to 3 lines, and it's still just as much "constant time" because the number of iterations is bounded.  (Your version isn't truly "constant time" anyway because different values will require different numbers of comparisons.)

Comment: @NateEldredge - yeah, I profiled this code against something I thought would perform worse, but got surprised, and ended up going with the truly constant time version (it's just `count += x >= 1000...000.f;` 36 times, which beat the best case of 2 conditional jumps somehow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if#Explanation):

> in nested if-statements, the else is associated with the closest if that doesn't have an else

So as long as every `if` has an `else`, nesting without brackets works fine. The problem occurs when an `else` should not be associated with the closest `if`. For example:

```cpp
    if ( condition1 ) {
        if ( condition2 )
            DoSomething();
    } // <-- This is needed so the else goes with the intended if.
    else
        DoOtherThing();
```

A quick scan of your code looks like it's fine.